# Keying react lists with dynamic properties

Tags: list, reactjs, key

I have a nested list:

- **foo**

  - bar

    - item
    - ...
  - baz

    - item
    - ...
- **qux**

  - ...

being generated from data like:

```
data = {
   foo: [{ bar: [{id:12345}, ...], baz: [{id: 23456}, ...}]}, {...}]
   qux: [...],
   ...
}
```

where the values in used as part of the keys (`foo`, `bar`, `baz`, and `qux` above) can be edited.

My approach for keying:

```
<ul>
  {Object.keys(data).sort().map(function(k1) {
    return [
      <li key={'k1-' + k1}><h3>{k1}</h3></li>,
      <ul>
        {Object.keys(data[k1]).sort().map(function(k2) {
          return [
            <li key={'k1-' + k1 + '-k2-' + k2}>
              <h4>{k2}</h4>
            </li>,
            <ul>
              data[k1][k2].map(function(item) {
                return (<li key={'k3-' + item.id}>blah blah blah</li>);
              })}
            </ul>
          ];
        })}
      </ul>
    ];
  })}
</ul>
```

is not handling cases where k1 and k2 change among existing values.

I've tried using the list index in the map function as part of the key, but that had similar problems when the list length/order changed on updates. I also tried calling `this.forceUpdate()` on relevant state changes, but that didn't seem to help.

Is there a keying approach that would rerender the list correctly when the keys are edited?

Answer (score 0):

As you need to have unique keys only within one list you can use indexes.

```
<ul>
  {Object.keys(data).sort().map(function(k1, i) {
    return [
      <li key={i}><h3>{k1}</h3></li>,
      <ul>
        {Object.keys(data[k1]).sort().map(function(k2, j) {
          return [
            <li key={[i,j].join('')}>
              <h4>{k2}</h4>
            </li>,
            <ul>
              data[k1][k2].map(function(item, k) {
                return (<li key={[i,j,k].join('')}>blah blah blah</li>);
              })}
            </ul>
          ];
        })}
      </ul>
    ];
  })}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy. When I try this, I have the same problem when items move within or between lists as an item's index can change when the lists get re`sort`ed but this isn't being reflected accurately in the rendered list. I don't think the index will work as the key when the items can move around like that.

Comment: you can use underscore `_.uniqueId([prefix]) ` to generate keys.
http://underscorejs.org/#identity or just strip out this function if you dont want to add whole lib.